# How can I repair heavy hardwood scraping?

Tags: repair, hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

We're moving out of our apartment and we need to repair the hardwood floor of our apartment for the next tenant that lives here.

Apologies as I cannot take a picture of the floor at the moment. I will try to describe the damage as best I can.

It is an oaken hardwood floor.  For a year and a half I have had a single coffee table with wooden legs placed between our two workstations in the center of the floor.  Every day or so, I or my wife will push the coffee table away to give ourselves more room on our side, and inevitably scrape away at the wooden floor beneath. This has resulted in a spot of scraping about as large as my hand (maybe a little smaller).

I'm not sure if we should use wood putty to fill in the area affected, since it's pretty substantial scraping (our TV is on this coffee table, so the damage is a little enhanced), or if we should just use a bit of sandpaper and finish/varnish on the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a picture it is a little hard to say.  Depending on the depth you may need to do one or both.

If the depth is shallow simply sand and refinish the spot (it will not look like new and particularly in certain light you will definitely always be able to see the spot).

If the scratches/gouges are deeper you will have to sand, fill, sand, then refinish and again, you will be able to tell its a patch job.  *edit*:  if the wood is stained you may also need to stain the spot prior to finishing as well.

Make sure you match the sheen on the finish.  (Satin/Semi-Gloss/Gloss)

And use furniture pads next time!!! :)

Comment: Furniture pads - One thing we need to get for our new apartment.  :) Thanks though, this is mighty helpful.  I think it's deep emough that we may need to do some light filling. The scratches from our refrigerator (we had to get something from behind it) were a little more obvious....and sadly we don't know if it's stained or not.

Comment: Post a picture if you can it should be pretty easy to tell.

Comment: Sadly, my phone camera is rather terrible and can't share pictures through anything but messages - I can't even upload them to my computer with a USB cable.  So a picture is impossible.  :(

Comment: Yikes.  C'mon phone upgrade date.